# MVC SiteMapProvider Breadcrumbs change ">" to something else

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvcsitemapprovider

The way the MVC SiteMapProvider lays out breadcrumbs they are displayed like

Home > Details > Manage Project

What do I do if I want to change ">" to a different symbol (or in my specific case an icon within twitter bootsrap)?

At the moment I am calling the breadcrumbs using @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()

I went into Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SiteMapPathHelperModel and tried changing

```
<text> &gt; </text>
```

to:

```
<text><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></text>
```

but the greater then symbol stayed. I received no errors.

Here is some potentially relevant code from the partial view that uses the bread crumbs:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) 
{

    <div class="breadcrumb trail">
        <i class="icon-home"></i>
        @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
    </div>            
    <p align ="right">   
    <i class="icon-user"></i> <text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
        [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
    </p>
}
else
{
    @* display nothing*@
}
```

Here is the sitemap being declared in the web.config:

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider" type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Mvc.Sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" cacheDuration="5" enableLocalization="true" scanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes="true" includeAssembliesForScan="" excludeAssembliesForScan="" attributesToIgnore="visibility" nodeKeyGenerator="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultNodeKeyGenerator, MvcSiteMapProvider" controllerTypeResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultControllerTypeResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" actionMethodParameterResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultActionMethodParameterResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" aclModule="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultAclModule, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapNodeUrlResolver="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeUrlResolver, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapNodeVisibilityProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" siteMapProviderEventHandler="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProviderEventHandler, MvcSiteMapProvider" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Code within the SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml template:

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapPathHelperModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Linq
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

@foreach (var node in Model) { 
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node);

    if (node != Model.Last()) {
       @*Original Symbol*@
       @* <text> &gt; </text> *@
       <text> &rsaquo; </text>
    }
}
```

Am I totally off in the way I am going about doing this, or am I just missing something?

**UPDATE** You can pass a template into the SiteMapPath method as a string. Attempting this within the partial view that calls this method, I pass it like so:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath("SiteMapPathHelperModel")
```

I have removed the acsx file from the project to keep it from going here by default (I want it to use the cshmtl template). I have changed the template code to use a different symbol and have rebuilt, saved all, then ran the project.

It still uses the default ">" symbol despite all of this.

Comment: Could you post the code in the template?

Comment: It is correct that the template uses '<' at the moment, this is what it contains. Didn't you change it?

Comment: @Xharze I did, to the icons, and also tried changing it to a different symbol but nothing changed.

Comment: @Xharze of MVCSiteMapProvider? 3.2.3.0 (via NuGet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming your .ascx file to something else. Even if you remove the file from the project it still may attempt to use it.

Comment: Not a problem, I ran into this problem on a project I was working on awhile back.